# Regex to replace \n\n after every second occuurence in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am converting `html` to `markdown` and vice versa.

When I convert `html` having multiple blank lines then I am getting following markdown.

```
"First Line↵↵ (Shouldn't be replaced)
 No Blank Line above this↵↵ (Shouldn't be replaced)
 ↵↵ (to be replaced)
 ↵↵  (to be replaced)
There are two empty new lines above this.↵↵ (Shouldn't be replaced)
 No empty line above this."
```

Now If I use `markdown.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>')` then it replaces the `\n\n` where it is not supposed to like in `First Line`.

I am not able to make a regex which can do this. I've also tried regex with `\b` but it doesn't worked for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

I've added space in markdown string for illustrative purpose. In general I get a complete string like this:"

```
"First Line↵↵No Blank Line above this↵↵↵↵↵↵There are two empty new lines above this.↵↵No empty line above this."
```

Comment: Try `markdown.replace(/\n\n((?:\n\n)+)/g, (_,x) => "\n\n" + x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>'))`. Or `.replace(/\n\n((?:\n\n)+)/g, function (_,x) { return "\n\n" + x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>'); })` to support ES5 (if needed). With the latest ECMAScript, you may even use `markdown.replace(/(?<=\n\n)\n\n/g, '<br>')`

Comment: Have you tried not re-inventing the wheel? https://github.com/domchristie/turndown

Comment: @Justinas turdown is not supporting conversion of `table` tags to markdown thats why I have'nt checked this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems like it is working, could you please explain a bit what is actually happening in your regex. I am not able to understand how it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match a double LF char and then a sequence of 1 or more occurrences of the double LF char, and only replace those that come after the first `\n\n`.

```
 .replace(/\n\n((?:\n\n)+)/g, function (_,x) { return "\n\n" + x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>'); })
```

or, to support ES5 (if needed)

```
.replace(/\n\n((?:\n\n)+)/g, function (_,x) { return "\n\n" + x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>'); })
```

or, if you target ECMAScript2018+:

```
.replace(/(?<=\n\n)\n\n/g, '<br>')
```

**Details**

- `\n\n` - two newlines
- `((?:\n\n)+)` - Capturing group 1 matching one or more (`+`) occurrences of a `\n\n` char sequence (note it is made a sequence by use of a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, where the `\n\n` are placed)

In the replacement, a callback method is used. It accepts a whole match (`_`) and Group 1  value (`x`). The return value is `"\n\n"` plus the result of `x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>')`, all `\n\n` occurrences are replaced with `<br>`.

The `/(?<=\n\n)\n\n/g` pattern matches all occurrences (`g`) of `\n\n` that are immediately preceded with `\n\n` (see the positive lookbehind `(?<=\n\n)`).

JS demo:

```js
var markdown = "First Line\n\nNo Blank Line above this\n\n\n\n\n\nThere are two empty new lines above this.\n\nNo empty line above this."
console.log(markdown.replace(/\n\n((?:\n\n)+)/g, function (_,x) { return "\n\n" + x.replace(/\n\n/g, '<br>'); }));
```